# How to unwrap a map so it sits straight

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to unwrap a map so it sits perfectly straight and aligned in both the x and y axis, I've tried using the follow active quads on a straight face but it only made things worse. Thanks in advance.

It should be like this
[image: It should be like this]

when I try follow active quad it becomes this mess
[image: when I try follow active quad it becomes this mess]

Comment: When I rebuild your object (except for those small inner faces which I couldn't figure out exactly, but to be honest I would unwrap them separately) with all its seams, I simply have to choose _Unwrap_, no active quads or anything, and I get the result you want. It is just rotated to best fit the space of the UV map, but I can rotate it to have the correct alignment.